# Why I can not loop through object in react-typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I can not loop throught object in react with typescript. I am using redux toolkit and I want to get chosenFilters arrays.

```
const chosenFilters = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.recipe.filters);
  for (const chosenFilterArray of chosenFilters) {
    console.log(chosenFilterArray);
  }


error: 

Type 'filters' is not an array type or a string type.


interface: 

export interface filters {
  filterTypes: string[];
  filterLengths: string[];
}
```

Comment: Because `filters` isn't an array.  It's an object with two properties which are arrays.  Are you trying to loop over one or both of those properties?  Loop over the properties of the object?  Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't iterate over an object with a for/of. But you can use `Object.valus(someObj)` to get the values from that object as an array and iterate over that.

```
for (const chosenFilterArray of Object.values(chosenFilters)) {
  console.log(chosenFilterArray);
}
```